# It deletes from DataGrid, but not Database

Tags: c#, database, datagrid, datasource

So I finally got my code somewhat working. So where it will delete from the Datagrid. But, It does not delete from the database at all.

I am using Data sources to do it.

Here is my button command.

```
private void delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid dg = this.nAMEDataGrid;

        if (dg != null)
        {
            var toDelete = (IList)dg.SelectedItems;
            var collection = toDelete.Cast<DataRowView>();
            var list = new List<DataRowView>(collection);

            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                item.Row.Delete();
            }
        }
    }
```

I just need it to delete from the database as well. But, I do not know why it isnt...

Comment: You delete rows objects only from in-memory collection. To delete it from database you should open DB connection and send some deletion commands.

Answer (score 0):

what about getting the id of your selected item from the grid and pass it as parameter to your database delete command then rebind your data grid?

Answer (score 0):

You still need to perform the operation against a database connection (which is usually best tied to the `DeleteCommand` event from the datagrid). The way to perform the database deletion depends on your data access strategy - if you are using Entity Framework, some other ORM, or directly tied to the SqlCommand and SqlConnection if using SQL Server.

Here's a full walkthrough:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/17e8f6/insert-update-and-delete-in-datagrid-in-Asp-Net/